# I need help on a simple PHP regular expression for matching a sequence of parentheses and any characters inside them

Tags: php, regex

I can't seem to figure this simple thing out.

basically I have entries like:

```
Bree@email.com (Bree Olsen)
(Daisy Marie) +015487572
etc
```

I need to use just the actual address or phone number. Hence I need to delete the `(any)`part of the strings.

Please advise

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Use `$string = trim(preg_replace('/\([^)]+\)/', '', $string));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$parenthesesContentRemoved = preg_replace('/\(.*\)/', '', $content);`

This should do the trick..

Or.. `$parenthesesContentRemoved = preg_replace('/\s?\(.*\)\s?/', '', $content);`

Which should also remove the spaces around the parentheses.

Comment: and it did beautifully!  :) I just need to get rid of the white space though but i figured ill do that outside of the regex w/ trim() function. Thanks very much

Comment: umm if i may ask a followup question. What if i have a string of many of the said string like "Bree@email.com (Bree Olsen),(Daisy Marie) +015487572,etc"  .. i want all occurrences of the (any) removed..

Comment: `$parenthesesContentRemoved = preg_replace('/\(.*\)/g', '', $content);` The global flag (/g) should work :)

Comment: I get an " Unknown modifier 'g'" error

Comment: My bad. preg_replace doesn't support modifiers. It does however replace all instances by default (which is what the /g usually does in regexes). Actually the given code should already do what you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23291/discussion-between-damien-overeem-and-brownchild)

Comment: yeh i thought so too (re preg_replace) but what seems to happen is the regex replaces everything in between only 2 parentheses, like "Bree@email.com (Bree Olsen),(Daisy Marie) +015487572, (Tori Black) tori@black.com"; results to  Bree@email.com tori@black.com (the first and last string, everything int he middle was removed.)

Comment: As i said in chat. Try making the regex ungreedy `/\(.*?\)/`

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(.*)\([^)]*\)(.*)$/$1$2/
```

Explained:

- ^ Anchor to beginning,
- (.*) any series of characters in group 1
- an opening bracket (
- any series of characters except a closing bracket [^)]*
- a closing bracket
- any series of characters in group 2